# How to populate form values after login in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I got a multi-step form where a user select a phone model, brand, etc and when they click get quote they get a price based on their selection.

To be able to confirm the quote, they need to put their address details or if they already have an account they can login.

The question is how can I redirect the user after they login to a different view with the quote details?

Thanks

Comment: Please put some code in there?

Comment: You may put all values such as brand, model, etc in session variable and use it in the view after login.

Comment: What code you have developed yet? You are asking for entire script which is really not possible to send here. Instead show us what you have did so far and then we will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default after users login they get redirected to /home. If you want to change this functionality just define a redirect path in your AuthController like this:

```
protected $redirectPath = '/your-show-quote-page';
```

Check [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) in Laravel Docs for more information

Based on your question, one way of doing what you want is:

1. Create a quotes table and store the quote information with your multi-step form,
2. Ask the user to login,
3. Redirect the user and show him the quote based on his selections.
4. Lastly, depending if the user is interested in buying the phone you can redirect him to one place or another and delete the quote when you don´t need it anymore.

Other way would be to store the information about the quote in the session and display it when needed. For this you can check [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session) in Laravel Docs. The process would be the same.

Hope it helps.